# Transforming many columns into 3 column categories which contains lists?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with 31 columns, which contains 3 categories "Classic", "Premium" and "Luxe" I want to swap the way the DataFrame works to have only 3 comumns "Classic", "Premium" and "Luxe" and 31 categories which can be listed inside.

Since I'm new I can only post a link to the picture for more clarity :
[Here is what I have and what I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0c5dT.png)

Here's what I tried so far:

Suppose we use this DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'Name': ["Alban","Benan","Conor","Dino","Egor","Fatima" ],'Virtual visits': ["Classique", "Classique","","" ,"Premium","Premium"], 'Cars' :["","" ,"Luxe","Luxe","Luxe", "Premium"],'Portraits' :["","" ,"Classique","Classique","Luxe", "Premium"],'Animals' :["Premium","Luxe" ,"","","Luxe", ""]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

    Name    Virtual visits  Cars       Portraits    Animals
0   Alban   Classique                  Premium
1   Benan   Classique                  Luxe
2   Conor   Luxe            Classique   
3   Dino    Luxe            Classique   
4   Egor    Premium         Luxe       Luxe         Luxe
5   Fatima  Premium         Premium    Premium
```

Using melt looked promising so I did that and a groupBy:

```
df = df.melt(id_vars=["Name"])
df.groupby(by=["Name"]).sum()

Name    variable                            value   
Alban   Virtual visitsCarsPortraitsAnimals  ClassiquePremium
Benan   Virtual visitsCarsPortraitsAnimals  ClassiqueLuxe
Conor   Virtual visitsCarsPortraitsAnimals  LuxeClassique
Dino    Virtual visitsCarsPortraitsAnimals  LuxeClassique
Egor    Virtual visitsCarsPortraitsAnimals  PremiumLuxeLuxeLuxe
Fatima  Virtual visitsCarsPortraitsAnimals  PremiumPremiumPremium
```

So the column "Variable" is made up of all the column names, which is not bad but instead of a single string added to one another, I would like to have a list, and instead of  columns Variable and Value, I would need to have 3 columns, "Premium", "Classque", "Luxe" and in each of them have the relevant list of categories appear.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were right with melt. After that you need a pivot table:

```
out = df.replace('',np.nan).melt("Name")\
.pivot_table(index="Name",columns="value",values="variable",aggfunc=','.join)\
.rename_axis(None,axis=1).reset_index()
```

---

```
print(out)

     Name       Classique                    Luxe  \
0   Alban  Virtual visits                     NaN   
1   Benan  Virtual visits                 Animals   
2   Conor       Portraits                    Cars   
3    Dino       Portraits                    Cars   
4    Egor             NaN  Cars,Portraits,Animals   
5  Fatima             NaN                     NaN   

                         Premium  
0                        Animals  
1                            NaN  
2                            NaN  
3                            NaN  
4                 Virtual visits  
5  Virtual visits,Cars,Portraits
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df.melt(id_vars=["Name"]).groupby(['Name', 'value']).apply(lambda x: list(x['variable'])).reset_index().pivot(index = 'Name', columns = 'value')
df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(1)
df = df.drop(columns =['']) # in case you have empty value represented by ''
```

```
value   Classique           Luxe                        Premium
Name            
Alban   [Virtual visits]    NaN                         [Animals]
Benan   [Virtual visits]    [Animals]                   NaN
Conor   [Portraits]         [Cars]                      NaN
Dino    [Portraits]         [Cars]                      NaN
Egor    NaN                 [Cars, Portraits, Animals]  [Virtual visits]
Fatima  NaN                 NaN                         [Virtual visits, Cars, Portraits]
```